# Compress backup file using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, backup, compression

Is it possible to compress a backup file to .zip (or another) in a stored procedure invoked from a maintenance plan?

My maintenance plan contains these steps:

- check DB (consistency, re_index, maybe not important)
- full backup
- to check backup file by using restore_verifyonly
- shrink database

After restore_verifyonly/shrink database I want to compress this file.

Comment: What is your version of SQL?

Comment: @RoKa SQL 2005/2008 R2 Standard, but for test purposes is possible on 2000 and 2012 too

Comment: SQL2008+ offers the ability to create a compressed backup which is approximately (very close at least) the same size as a zipped backup.  Would that not be a viable solution rather than tinkering in a third party tool? @mKorbel

Comment: @RoKa we are resticted (internally) to use shellexec e.g., then 3rd. party couldn't be executed from standard procedure, or am I wrong

Comment: The most obvious way to use a 3rd party tool in this case would be to use `xp_cmdshell`, so if you are restricted from doing that, it will not work.  There may of course be other options, such as a CLR proc (don't even bother), or a scheduled task (don't bother either).  If you are planning to do this on PROD on a SQL2008 or later version, why don't you just create a compressed backup in the first place using `WITH COMPRESSION`?

Comment: @RoKa could be partial solution for DB engines where is  instaled 2008 version

Comment: If you need to support 2000 and 2005 then you should consider not doing this from a procedure at all. RedGate's backup tool, for example, can manage all of your backups, including compression, and take the place of any maintenance plan. You can perform your checkdbs etc. separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Backup compression was introduced in SQL 2008 Enterprise, and in SQL2008R2 and later, added to Standard Edition.

When creating a backup, you can specify the `WITH COMPRESSION` keyword, which will ensure that the database backup size is compressed to approximately a similar size as a zipped 'normal' backup file.

For SQL2005 or older, the best way really (other than using a specific tool like RedGate) is to ensure that `xp_cmdshell` is enabled on the instances, and then use a command line to compact using for e.g. WinRar.

I use a cmd file that looks something like this:

```
@echo off
Set "winrarPath=C:\Program Files\WinRAR"
"%winrarPath%\winrar.exe" a -r "ZippedBackup.zip" "BackupFile.BAK"
```

You can then execute this cmd file from your 2000 / 2005 instances.  You can also play around with passing `%1`-type variables to the cmd file, if your filenames are not generic.